# React variable evaluation when 'push' JSX elements in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pushing JSX elements in an array

```
for (category of this.state.categories) {
  categories.push(
    <li>
      <label 
        className="tree-toggler nav-header list-group-item" 
        onClick={() => this.showHideConnectorNames(category)}
      >
        {category}
      </label>
      <ul 
        className="tree ul-no-style" 
        id={category+'Connectors'}
      >
      </ul>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Problem is that `category` variable in `this.showHideConnectorNames(category)` method call evaluates to last `category` in `this.state.categories` array (so 'cat2' for all elements). It is evaluated correctly at all the other places, such as inside the `<label>`.

So I have to do this:

```
for (category of this.state.categories) {
  if (category === 'cat1')
    categories.push(
      <li>
        <label 
          className="tree-toggler nav-header list-group-item" 
          onClick={() => this.showHideConnectorNames('cat1')}
        >
          {category}
        </label>
        <ul 
          className="tree ul-no-style" 
          id={category + 'Connectors'}
        >
        </ul>
      </li>
    ); 
  else if (category === 'cat2')
    categories.push(
      <li>
        <label 
          className="tree-toggler nav-header list-group-item" 
          onClick={() => this.showHideConnectorNames('cat2')}
        >
          {category}
        </label>
        <ul 
          className="tree ul-no-style" 
          id={category + 'Connectors'}
        >
        </ul>
      </li>
    );
  else
    categories.push(
      <li>
        <label 
          className="tree-toggler nav-header list-group-item" 
          onClick={() => this.showHideConnectorNames(category)}
        >
          {category}
        </label>
        <ul 
          className="tree ul-no-style" 
          id={category + 'Connectors'}
        >
        </ul>
      </li>
    );
}
```

Is this a React issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you post your entire component?

Comment: I think you're missing brackets `{ }` on your conditional statements. `if () { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using for of incorrectly to prevent using it incorrectly I like to use map instead:

```
const categories = this.state.categories.map(category => (
  // not sure what to use for key here but it's missing
  <li key={category.id}>
    <label
      className="tree-toggler nav-header list-group-item"
      onClick={() => this.showHideConnectorNames(category)}
    >
      {category}
    </label>
    <ul
      className="tree ul-no-style"
      id={category + 'Connectors'}
    ></ul>
  </li>
));
```

This is because category is set in every loop iteration so after the loop is finished category is the last one. That is why by the time you click on your component the category is always the last one from this.state categories.

Here is a demo showing the bahavior:

```js
let category,categories=[],cats=[1,2,3];
//you re assing category every time
for (category of cats) {
  categories.push(
    ()=>console.log('category is now:',category)
  );
}
//now category is the last one
console.log('category after loop:',category);
//now I execute the functions category is the last one
categories.forEach(cat=>cat())
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you want to do with the array after it's built, but I think using a `map` call would be quite a bit more efficient.  Just place this inside your return statement wherever you want to render your list items:

```
<ul>
  {this.state.categories.map(cat => (
    // your li has a missing key property
    <li>
      <label
        className="tree-toggler nav-header list-group-item"
        onClick={() => this.showHideConnectorNames(cat)}
      >
        {cat}
      </label>
      <ul
        className="tree ul-no-style"
        id={cat + 'Connectors'}
      ></ul>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

just add let, then category will be local inside for scope

`for (let category of this.state.categories)`

Comment: yes, that will fix it too because you create a new category variable but I prefer just mapping this.state.categories.

Comment: These are two different issues:
in sence of react app, mapping is much more correct, of course,
but just to point out a scope misunderstanding i wrote this solution